Why can't I resolve a promise via a ref stored resolve function in React?
I'm trying to create a promisify style hook, the idea is to eventually use it with Redux Toolkit to allow using the new React 19 use hook.
Here's the gyst of how this thing would work:
function usePromise(input: {
    isLoading: true,
    data: null
} | {
    isLoading: false,
    data: string;
}) {


    // Store the resolve function in a ref 
    const resRef = useRef<(data: string) => void>(null);

    // Create a new promise 
    // Store the resolve function in the ref 
    const promiseRef = useRef(
        new Promise((res) => {
            resRef.current = res;

            //res("xxx") //  this will resolve though
        })
    );

    // When input changes, if there is data, resolve the promise
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!input.isLoading) {
            resRef.current?.(input.data);
        }

    }, [input]);

    // Return the promise 
    return promiseRef.current;
}

With usage like:
export function MyComponent() {

    const [value, setValue] = useState<null | string>(null);

    const prom = usePromise(value ? {
        isLoading: false,
        data: value
    } : {
        isLoading: true,
        data: null
    });

    prom.then((v) => alert(v))

    return <div >

        <button onClick={() => setValue("123")}>Click me</button>
    </div>
}

Here, I would expect that when we click the button, the promise would resolve and we see the alert. However, it does not.
What's going on here?
I have a reproduction for this issue here: https://github.com/dwjohnston/react-promise-issue

Even with this issue being solved to show an alert, your current implementation adds multiple .then() callbacks to the same promise instance every time your component rerenders. So you're going to get an alert for every single rerender your component has done once the issue is fixed. Is that the expected behavior?

@NickParsons it doesn't matter. It's for demonstration only, that the promise isn't being resolved at all.

Your problem is that you are creating a new promise every time the hook runs, setting resRef.current to the resolver function of that last promise. However only the first promise that is passed to the useRef hook is stored in promiseRef.current.
To fix this, avoid recreating the promise:
function usePromise(input) {
    const resRef = useRef();
    const promiseRef = useRef();
    if (!promiseRef.current) {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        promiseRef.current = new Promise(resolve => {
            resRef.current = resolve;
        });
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!input.isLoading) {
            resRef.current(input.data);
        }
    }, [input]);
    return promiseRef.current;
}

Alternatively, use a state that is initialised with a callback:
function usePromise(input) {
    const [{ promise, resolve }] = useState(() => Promise.withResolvers());
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!input.isLoading) {
            resolve(input.data);
        }
    }, [input]);
    return promise;
}


or maybe const resolvers = useMemo(() => Promise.withResolvers(), []); to avoid the need for the refs as another option

Brilliant thanks. I was aware it would be creating new promises and not using them, but didn't think about how it would clobber the resRef.

@NickParsons Yes, although I prefer to use useState for that purpose, useMemo is not guaranteed to run only once
